# How to submit/auto-save a SharePoint Quick Edit form programmaticly

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

i have a Sharepoint list, viewing its data in quick edit form...currently im facing an issue if i do not press *Stop Editing* the current entered data will not be saved. i have done some research and found one useful post where the user is simulating the enter button to save the entered data (Link below)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bac2fe52-a513-4949-9b63-9e24b69f8715/autosave-list-record?forum=sharepointdevelopment

However my attempt is not work expected...looking for other solutions or fix my current attempt.

My attempt:

```
      // THIS CODE WILL SIMULATE ENTER ENTER AFTER 5 SECONDS OF USER STOP TYPING
        var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
        var doneTypingInterval = 5000;  //time in ms, 5 second for example
        var $input = $(window);

//on keyup, start the countdown
        $input.on('keyup', function () {
            clearTimeout(typingTimer);
            typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
        });

//on keydown, clear the countdown 
        $input.on('keydown', function () {
            clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        });

//user is "finished typing," do something
        function doneTyping () {

            var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
            e.which = 13; //choose the one you want
            e.keyCode = 13;
            $(window).trigger(e); // simulat the enter button 


            console.log("done typing now saving!@")
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: i solved this issue by closing the quick edit mode and re-opening.

Use this to open Quick Edit:

```
InitGridFromView(window['WPQ2SchemaData'].View);
```

Use this to exit Grid View:

```
ExitGrid(window['WPQ2SchemaData'].View);
```